# Eclipse View disappears after application restart

Tags: eclipse, e4

I have added a view with the SWT Browser into my 3.x application running in 4.2 runtime.
After a fresh install the browser view is displayed, but after the first run the view has
disappeared.

I found out that in the runtime workspace a file

```
   '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi '
```

has been created. This contains a line

```
  ... elementId="com.hjb.pm.ui.views.BrowserView" toBeRendered="false" ....
```

If I change the `toBeRendered` flag to `true`, everything is fine for one application run.
How can I control this flag?

As a work around I have added `-clearPersistedState` to my command line arguments. This ignores the saved state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found after filing an eclipse bug [409382](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409382).

My fault was to specify *restorable=false* for this view in the **plugin.xml**. After setting this
to *false*, the *tobeRendered="false"* disappears from the **workbench.xmi**.

The work around is no longer needed.